# "CAPTCHA" - making a version that is easier

Tags: captcha

I am setting up a web site and going to use "captcha" to prevent robots.

I get rather annoyed with some of the systems where you have to try and try again as the words are unreadable.

Therefore I am just going to use these letters/numbers

```
acdefhkmnpqrstwxyz 234578
```

This is in the hope that it will avoid some confusion (e.g. 1 and l).

Is there any other things that I should consider?

Comment: Just fed up with some web sites (e.g. Gumtree) where you have to go through many images before one is readable. Sort of puts people off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- easier for humans, easier for robots...
- think about visually impaired people, they hate captcha even more
- why [reinventing the wheel](http://www.google.com/recaptcha)?

Answer (score -1):

To add on to Tomasz answer 
reCaptcha is for a worthwhile cause, use it.

Comment: No. Don't use it, good cause or not (and *good cause * is **never** a reason to choose a technology or code base), making people jump through reCaptcha hoops is bad UX.